# get duration in digital form

Tags: java, android

I have a music player which has a function called `getcurrentposn` which returns the current position in milliseconds, I want to display the result in the TextView in this form `mm:ss`.

I made a `getAsTime` function which have returns the time in my app in the  digital form i.e. `mm:ss`.

This is what I tried:

```
   long minutes =  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis); 
   long seconds = minutes * 60;
   if(millis!=0) {
        long totalSeconds =  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis);
        if(seconds!=0)
        seconds = totalSeconds / seconds;
        else seconds=totalSeconds;
    }


    if(minutes<10 && seconds <10)
        return "0"+minutes + ":" +"0"+ seconds;


    if(minutes<10 && seconds>=10)
        return "0"+minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if(minutes>=10 && seconds<10)
        return minutes + ":" +"0"+ seconds;

    return minutes+":"+seconds;

}
```

But the problem with that it is doesn't seem to work correctly.

Is there any inbuilt function to do so?  if not how do I achieve it the correct way?

Example: `01:00`
         `02:09`

Comment: You should be treating minutes and seconds separately. Also, what is the actual problem you are having?

Comment: You want to get time manually? why?

Comment: @ACV for some millisecods time show is almost same even though miliseconds vary by 1000 ms

Comment: @Ibrahim i have a music player which has a function called getcurrentposn which returns the current position in milliseconds, i want to display the result in the textview in this form

Comment: @downvoter why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert the milliseconds to seconds:

```
int t = millis / 1000;
```

Then convert those to minutes and seconds

```
int minutes = t / 60; //since both are ints, you get an int
int seconds = t % 60;
```

Then return a string formatted like you want it with added padding

```
return String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
```